# Android Retrofit: use or not use RxAndroid?

Tags: android, api, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I've been searching the best way to do `API-calls`, and for that, I did some research on the main ways, like `Retrofit`, `Volley`, `Ion` etc, and I'm convinced that `Retrofit` is really the best. I'm used to use this one since a long time, and I should just move on and live my life, with my mind full of happiness about my past choices, BUT, I only use `Retrofit`, and its calls treatments, where I usually do my stuff, treating `success` and `error`, and it works fine, GG. So, I heard about `RxAndroid` on `Retrofit`, and then I got myself in a huge doubt about myself:

**Should I implement `RxAndroid`?**

It's going to make my projects better? What are the benefits of using (or not) it?

Comment: "It's going to make my projects better?" Maybe, but maybe not. It might make your code worse if you don't use the added possibilities to your advantage. It's added complexity after all.-

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you probably mean `RxJava` in this context.  RxJava and Retrofit fit very nicely together....particularly if you need to for example combine execution of different requests.  For example say you have following and you want to get token before calling `getData`

```
public interface SomeRetrofitServiceInterface {
    @POST("issueToken")
    Observable<String>  issueToken(@Query("subscriptionKey") String subscriptonKey);

    @GET("getSomeData")
    Observable<MyPojo> getData(@Query("token") String token);
}
```

this is how you can do this using RxJava

```
service.issueToken(subscriptionKey)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(token -> service.getData(token));
```

Another use case might be where you want to run a number of requests in parallel (e.g. using `Observable.zip()` and wait for them all to complete before doing further processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already familiar with the whole RX-way of thinking, I would say: give it a try. For me, it made things in my app way easier, but the impact is dependent on how your app is setup.

If you're not familiar with RX, I would suggest you first try to grasp the idea behind it, incorporating it in some small parts in your app, without using it in combination with Retrofit.

And last but certainly not least: Don't use it because it's hip and happening, try it out first, if you find it valuable for your code, keep on using it.

Answer (score 0):

RxJava like each library have same negative affects for performance and size of your application. In this case it is not a big overhead. RxJava is simple and improves the quality of your code. When you start to use it, you will use it in all of your projects.